# Trimble GNSS Disconnected in TerraSync

Tags: gps, trimble, terrasync

I've been trying to get our Trimble up and running after a couple years of not using it. It will connect to satellites alright, but it won't show as connected in TerraSync. I've tried rebooting the machine a couple times, the program a couple times, changing ports and settings, resetting the system GNSS but it still won't connect. Any tips/solutions?

Using TerraSync 5.81.

Comment: You might want to provide the full list of what has / has not changed since the latest setup that worked ? (SW version, device, cable type...)

Comment: What Trimble device are you using?  If it is an external receiver, what Windows / Windows embedded device is TerraSync running on? How do you know the device is tracking satellites?